# See which domains use a Google Maps API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-developers-console, google-cloud-console

Is there any way to check which domains/websites use a specific API like "Google Maps Embed API" in console.cloud.google.com?

It's a project with multiple keys which don't indicate where they were used.

Background: There is a key used on multiple sites and I want to see which site causes the most traffic.

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this? The 1 answer doesn't seem to resolve this...

Comment: No, actually not. I just build a crawler for all domains I know, that searched for the key. Took way longer than expected, but worked.

Comment: Cannot believe Google doesn't make this easier.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar need, ended up using a source code search engine like 
https://publicwww.com/
fill in your API key. Be sure to add " depth:all" in your request to get results from internal pages as well (in case your google maps call is on contact page for example)

For example you would try "myKey_here depth:all" in the search engine

Concerns :
1/ only works on top 500M sites (but chances are, yours is part of it)
2/ you have to subscribe a paid plan to see the whole details, but most of the times, you can "guess" the relevant domain name with the (partly hidden)result 
3/ won't work if your site is not crawlable by search engines
4/ trick based on finding the API Key as a parameter, so results may not be comprehensive

Nethertheless, perfectly did the job for me.

Comment: This is not good for all situations like me, you have to pay to view the domain

Answer (score -4):

Typically, API KEYS are generated per project not per site. See [API KEYS](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158858?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490). The restrictions could help you determine which sites are allowed to use the API. The Domain/IP(s) allowed per API KEY could restrict the sites allowed access to the alloted API KEY [quotas](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#total-usage-limits) which would make sense to peruse through if the restrictions exist as a preventive measure.. With that being said, you could parse for your keys per site and then evaluate those API Keys in the [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/) by following -->

'Sign-in' > Select the right project from the drop-down menu (different projects usually have different API Keys associated as they are generated on a per-project basis) > (hover over) 'APIs & Services' > Review activity... For a more thorough, detailed analysis, you could visit [Premium Plan Reporting Overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/reports/#support-portal-usage-reports).

Comment: If there no restrictions and the key is used on multiple sites, this solution wont work